# ASP.NET Tutorials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

can you recommend some good ASP.NET tutorials or a good book?
Should I jump right to ASP.NET MVC/html/javascript or learn web forms first?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great book if you're just beginning is Matthew MacDonald's [Beginning ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008: From Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598911). Once you're done with that a great reference (also by MacDonald) is [Pro ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598938). One of my favorite sources of information online is [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027112438/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MVC or WebForms...it's your choice but if I can offer one piece of advice regarding webforms...I know it'll be tempting to start dropping controls and playing with code, but it will help you A LOT if you don't skip over learning about the request and page lifecycles...a couple weeks later you'll thank yourself for spending the extra time there.

Answer (score 0):

MVC www.asp.net/mvc great videos
Asp.net www.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use ASP.NET MVC, then go straight to it. But it's a fairly new technology, not even in beta yet, so have that in mind. However, the application model is totally different compared to ASP.NET, so it is not in fact a replacement. For tutorials, you can surely check out http://www.asp.net and http://www.asp.net/mvc - there's tons of information there.

Answer (score 0):

A site for web tutorials including ASP.net can be found [here](http://msconline.maconstate.edu/tutorials/default.aspx).